VSCodium Not Recognizing Python Module in Virtual Environment
I activated the virtual environment of my project via the terminal and then opened the project path in VSCodium. Despite installing the Python library globally, VSCodium still doesn't recognize the module.
Additional information:

VSCodium version: 1.91.1 (release: 24193)
Python version: 3.12.3
Operating system: Ubuntu 24.04

screenshot

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'


Activated the virtual environment: source venv/bin/activate
Opened VSCodium: 'codium .'
Installed the Python library globally: sudo apt install python3-pandas
Also, tried to log out and reopen. But the issue isn't solved.


user: $ cd code_projects/gps_data_2107/
user: ~/code_projects/gps_data_2107$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) user: ~/code_projects/gps_data_2107$ codium.
(venv) user: ~/code_projects/gps_data_2107$ sudo apt install python3-pandas
[sudo] password for user:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
python3-pandas is already the newest version (2.1.4+dfsg-7). upgraded, newly installed, to remove and 1 not upgraded.
(venv) user: ~/code_projects/gps_data_2107$


This question is similar to: VSCodium Fails to Detect Virtual Environment Interpreter. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

you are correct that the questions are quite similar since both involve launching the virtual environment via the terminal. However, the major difference is that the question you refer to is about recognizing the virtual environment itself, whereas my issue is specifically about recognizing the module after ensuring that the virtual environment kernel is in use. Therefore, your question doesn't address my problem.
